# The Secret Current

Tags: performing

I saw this guitarist named Leo Kottke.
In speaking he mentioned something called The Secret Current.  He said it is something that is there before the performance happens.  It has the flow of how the performance should go.  And that it's when the performer tries to manipulate it, and taking total control of its course is when bad things happen.  He also added that it's something that we are all involved in (performer and audience) and a part of.

Have any of you had an experience like this or have any further insights to this?

Comment: Sounds like it's just his own little philosophy about the mindset and interactions involved in a live performance. For a live performance to be good, the audience and performer has to connect in some way, that's the "something we're all involved in" part. That it's there before the performance could be that the performer needs to be focused in order to deliver. Pure speculation of course, but it's not any concept I've heard of before.

Comment: Yea, sounds like it's his own way of describing something that a lot of musicians have experienced. My version is "don't get in the way of the music."

Comment: This is a great question and an interesting subject, but I voted to close because I think it is better suited for a discussion on Meta or Chat.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard this being referred to as being "in the groove". There could be a number of factors contributing to this. Some that occur to me are:

**Intuition** - Often, when you've played an instrument for a while, you come to a point where you play by "feel" or by intuition. You aren't necessarily thinking about what notes or chords you're playing, or what the timing is, because it all comes from feel; it's similar to how, when talking, you don't consciously think about exact tongue placement or individual chest, throat, and facial muscles. If you then try to switch out of this intuitive mindset, into a more analytical mindset, it's like changing gears, and the brief cognitive dissonance can take you out of the moment.

**Being "in the moment"** - Often, musical performers (and hopefully the audience as well) get into a certain mindset where they become hyper-aware of the present, without thinking of the past or future. This also clears the mind, and can contribute to a sense of time "slowing down". This is probably related to (if not the same as) a meditative or trance-like state.

**Entrainment** - It's been shown that brain waves can become entrained to a musical rhythm. This means that the performers and audience can end up thinking "in time" with one another.

Comment: Good answer, I would also add that the "Current" he is referring to might involve the give and take between a performer and the audience.  I have only played a handful of live shows, but when you are up on stage you can really feel the energy of the crowd and feed off it. I would assume if you are a seasoned performer that energy would help you play better, in turn increasing the audience's enjoyment, and giving you back more positive energy as a result. So in this way it is like an electrical feedback circuit, where the energy goes in a circle from performer to audience and back.